# Interact with token contract

Tags: erc-20, dapps

I am trying to create a simple contract to interact with it, but it seems I always get 0 when I try to retrieve my balance and I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I have coins and it should return the correct balance.

Solidity:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-only
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

import "IERC20.sol";

contract TestContract {

IERC20 testToken = IERC20(my_token_address_here);

function GetUserTokenBalance(address name) public view returns(uint256){ 
   name = msg.sender;
   return testToken.balanceOf(name);
}

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to do it, it seems that I was doing some wrong associations.
See below the correct code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-only
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;

import "IERC20.sol";

contract TestContract {

IERC20 token;

constructor() {
    token = IERC20(my_token_here);
}

function GetUserTokenBalance(address name) public view returns(uint256){ 
   return token.balanceOf(name);
}

}
```

Comment: In your original post you've overriden the name variable with `msg.sender` every time. So you weren't querying for the account in function parameter, but for the account the transaction came from.